# Can I use a different public key for DKIM signatures for the same domain?

Tags: opendkim

Can I have separate public keys for the following :

support@mydomain.com
myaddr@mydomain.com

I am using a keytable so my initial feel is to create the keys using a different selector and since I am using the keytable, the selector referenced in opendkim.conf will be ignored. Am I on the right track and if not, how would I accomplish using 2 keys for the same domain but different emails as in above.

Comment: Could you please share what is benefit for this use case? DKIM signature is in principle signature related to the server handling some domain. There is regular approach for more keys but it is scenario where there are more servers and each of them are using own key (the key should not be shared over the servers). In this approach you just "match" which key to use for the domain and all the public keys (differs in selector ID / name) have to be available in the DNS records.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish many different DKIM keys using DNS under the same domain, for example;

server1._domainkey.yourdomain.com

server2._domainkey.yourdomain.com

Here you can see that they are both published at the root of the domain yourdomain.com, and differentiated by the selector server1 and server2.
However, for this to work your email server must support selecting between these different keys somehow, which varies from server to server. If you email server doesn't understand how to use different keys for different senders, you could split this problem into a subdomain as a workaround:

server1._domainkey.yourdomain.com

server2._domainkey.subdomain.yourdomain.com

This way your email server can treat everything as separate domains, and use the proper key for each domain.